# why file "web.xml" has useless <taglib>

Tags: jsp, tomcat, web.xml, taglib

Why file "web.xml" has useless `<taglib>`?
Now I use tomcat 7 and surprisingly finding out I can use `taglib` in `web.xml`,but when I finally know what it means,I really think it useless.
I want tomcat design in this way,if I configure taglib in web.xml then I don't have to configure `taglib` in jsp file,on the contrary,if I configure `taglib` in jsp file then I don't have to configure `taglib` in web.xml.

Comment: @Stefan That should probably be an answer and not just a comment... just add some references.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to configure [custom taglibs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnawn.html) in web.xml anymore, its just for legacy support. Taglibs will be [scanned](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/jar-scanner.html) when the server starts, so you only need to define them in your JSP.